# How to configure Java8TimeDialect manually in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Since I'm using Thymeleaf only for email template processing (not for view creation), I have the following exclusion in my application class (i.e. a class extending `SpringBootServletInitializer`):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Absent Spring Boot's autoconfiguration, I need to configure the Java8TimeDialect class manually, so I've added the following bean to my ThymeleafConfig class:

```
@Bean
public Java8TimeDialect java8TimeDialect() {
    return new Java8TimeDialect();
}
```

Nonetheless, I'm still getting the following exception:

> Attempted to call method
>   format(java.time.LocalDateTime,java.lang.String) on null context
>   object

Clearly the `temporals` object isn't being added to the context. How can I resolve this?

I've included Thymeleaf in my POM file as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you declare a bean of type `SpringTemplateEngine`? If you did, you could try to call `templateEngine.addDialect(java8TimeDialect());` when configuring the `TemplateEngine` bean.

Comment: @Cos64 I do, and that worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then:

```
package com.users.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.java8time.dialect.Java8TimeDialect;

import nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect;

@Configuration
public class Thymeleaf {

    //TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();

    @Bean
    public Java8TimeDialect java8TimeDialect() {
        return new Java8TimeDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
        return new LayoutDialect();
   }
```

Finnally:

```
The time is: <strong th:text="${#temporals.format(now, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm')}">31/12/2015 15:00</strong>
```