# Formatting LocalDateTime in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have following code

```html
<span th:text="${#temporals.format(station.getDepartureDateTime(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}"></span>
```

I have added dependency in pom

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It must show `2020-12-12` but it show full date like `2020-12-12T12:45:35.375` (it was the same without any formatting).

No errors appeared.

How can I format this LocalDateTime?

Comment: Did you add `Java8TimeDialect` to the template engine as shown at https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time#installation ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084013/how-to-configure-java8timedialect-manually-in-a-spring-boot-application if you are using Spring Boot.

Comment: That code works for me -- using the same exact method call.  Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: @Metroids I evalute this variable and everything is good